# Android: Merging 2 ArrayList with same index

Tags: android, arraylist

I have my two arraylist and I want to merg their data like this

```
    ArrayList prayerNames={Fajar,Zohar,Asar,Magrib,Isha};

    ArrayList prayerTime={4:04am,2:58pm,4:20pm,5:09pm,8:10pm}
```

I want this type of merged array..

```
    {Fajar 4:04am, Zohar 2:58pm , Asar 4:20pm, Magrib 5:09pm,Isha 8:10pm}
```

I have tried merged.addAll()function but its not giving me the exact same outsput.
Can any one help me out of this.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try this..

```
ArrayList<String> new_list = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i = 0; i < prayerNames.size(); i++){
    new_list.add(prayerNames.get(i)+" "+prayerTime.get(i))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better will be to create map of two lists. With lists something like

```
Iterator<String> i1 = prayerNames.iterator();
Iterator<String> i2 = prayerTime.iterator();
while (i1.hasNext() && i2.hasNext()) {
    map.put(i1.next(), i2.next());
}
if (i1.hasNext() || i2.hasNext()) complainAboutSizes();
```

Comment: I didn't get your logic...sorry can u explain a little bit more

Comment: I think you are looking to map elements from one ArrayList to same index element in another ArrayList. And there might be a case where length of two arraylist is not exactly same.

Comment: No the length of array list is same both have 5 ,5 elements